# Copy jar file from one project to another using maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have the following project structure.

```
Root
 |--> Project-A (It generates war) +  test.jar
 |--> Project-B (It only generates war)
```

I have a web application name 'Project-A' which when I do `mvn clean package` it generates `Project-A.war` and `test.jar` in target folder.
Similarly, I have a web application name 'Project-B' which when I do `mvn clean package` it generates only `Project-B.war`

WHAT I WANT is when I do `mvn clean package` for 'Project-B', `test.jar` should part of that war file or inside 'Project-B' libs?

Can anyone please suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to host your artifacts internally using a Repository Manager so they can be consumed by other projects, here are few popular ones.

1. [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/)
2. [Nexus Repository](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype)

Here is an article that have more deails [How to setup a Private Maven Repository](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en)

Would recommend reading more about [Repository Managemers](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html), this link have more options.

Cheers !